# tmux: why do these two lines cause a ".tmux.conf:2: can't establish current session" on startup?

Tags: configuration, tmux

I have only these 2 lines in ~/.tmux.conf:

```
unbind r
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf; display "Reloaded"
```

I start up tmux with just

```
tmux
```

And

```
/Users/.../.tmux.conf:2: can't establish current session
```

is the result.

Why is this, and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a typo in the second command; you need to escape the semicolon. See the example in `man tmux`:

> bind-key R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; \
>            display-message "source-file done"

As the manual goes on to explain:

> Multiple commands may be specified together as part of a command sequence.  Each command should be separated by spaces and a semicolon; commands are
>      executed sequentially from left to right and lines ending with a backslash continue on to the next line, except when escaped by another backslash.  *A
>      literal semicolon may be included by escaping it with a backslash (for example, when specifying a command sequence to bind-key)*.

Comment: Yes, not escaping the semicolon means that the `display-message` command is actually executed when the server is first starting. This happens before the initial client has actually attached, and before there are any panes, thus the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. I guess I should consider searching for particular examples in the man page.

Answer (score 12):

I just had this error message when I had a few `set` commands in there which didn't have the `-g` flag. So if someone has that problem, try adding `-g` to your `set`s.

Comment: This was my issue. Without `-g`, tmux is defaulting to a session (-s) setting (the type is inferred from the option name - other possibilities are -w and -p for window and pane options).